# Making text span the entire width of the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make text span the entire width of the page, like so:

http://www.thecut.net.au/

I've looked at the source, but am unable to make sense of how they achieve this. Some direction would be useful -- thanks.

Comment: `background: url(../images/the-cut.svg) no-repeat top center;
background-size: 104%;`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about replicating something on a live page.

Comment: This question lacks a clear problem statement and becomes meaningless if the live page cited is removed or essentially changed.

Answer (score 3):

[Learn how to use your browser's inspector](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index). It's very easy to work out what you wanted to know:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution for the website you mention is to use an image. Images are much easier to control the appearance of, especially when accounting for the many different browsers and screen sizes available now.

Two ways to display an image that spans the width of the webpage are:

1. Image tags: `<img id="largeTextImage" src="image URL" style="width:100%;" />`
2. Background Images: `<div id="largeTextDiv" style="background: url(image URL) no-repeat top center;"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Image is definitely the way to go if you're trying to reach a pixel perfect look and to simplify your life.

Otherwise, you could also look at using different font-sizes and using media queries so that depending on the width of the window, a different font size would show up. This wouldn't be recommended though.